# free() blocking other threads, system slowdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I'm working on a multithreaded plugin. When I do a free() on quite large blocks of memory ( > 10 MB ) the application with my plugin temporarily slows down too much. ( Its an audio app, the audio thread gets too less time ).
I'm not sure if the free() is using a lot of CPU or that it is blocking other threads way too long.
Its seems that a call to madvice() is doing a lot of work. I'm used to free() taking up not much time ( it does not when I run in 32 bits mode ).

some info:
OSX 10.8
64 bits plugin & program
C++

Any suggestions on how to continue are very welcome.

Comment: Maybe free is taking too much time because it clears the memory for debugging purposes. Get a version of free that does not do that..

Comment: Can you instrument the program - on OS X it is really easy to do using instruments. That'll tell you where exactly your program is spending most of its time.

Comment: You should avoid memory allocation or deallocation on any real-time priority audio callback threads. See the recommendations in [Technical Q&A QA1467: CoreAudio Overload Warnings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1467/_index.html). The malloc implementation takes locks for thread-safety.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious suggestion would of course be to stop doing the `free()` (which should be some form of `delete` in C++, by the way).

Don't free the memory as long as your plugin is still loaded and active (or maybe "running"), free the resources when the plugin no longer needs to be around.

If you need to re-allocate a new buffer after freeing the old, figure out a way to re-use the already allocated memory, instead.

Comment: +1 That's the way i ended up doing this in a synchronized realtime video player.

Comment: I wish I could do that, my memory requirements are dependant on the choosen preset a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you reuse the memory, perhaps with placement `new`, then you can get rid of the call to `free/delete` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

if the buffer is the same size or nearly so you may benefit from delaying the free, and instead using a realloc(). this can be trickier.

Answer (score 0):

For large allocations I use now vm_allocate() which does not seem to call a lengthy madvice().

Since I use vm_allocate() and its counterpart vm_deallocate() all memory releasing calls are fast again.